# How do I add plugins to a singleplayer world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing Minecraft 1.9.2. I want to install Bukkit or some other plugin to my single-player world. I know it is possible to install plugins on multi-player servers, but I'm not sure about single-player. Is it possible? If it is, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins are for bukkit servers, you need the Bukkit API to run them. In other words; **you can't run plugins in singleplayer**.

What you can do is run a public bukkit server in which only you can join. To do this:

1. Op yourself '/OP'
2. Edit server.properties and set max value to 0
3. Edit the ops.json and change your 'Bypass Player limit ' to true

Comment: Just clarifying: This set of instructions is for a server, not singleplayer?

Comment: Yes. To run bukkit plugins you need a server. This is going over how to make it private, will post a link to a tutorial on creating the whole server

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://bukkit.org/threads/tutorial-using-bukkit-plugins-in-singleplayer.66013/) may help you.

The simple answer is, this is not possible.  However, it is possible to run a small non-port-forwarded server and connect to it with `localhost`.  Here's a direct quote for those of you that don't like links:

> Ever saw a really awesome plugin, and thought "Wow, I'd really love to have that as a mod for singleplayer!"
>
> WELL YOU CAN! Here's how:
>
> Download the Bukkit server and save it into a folder on your desktop.*
>
> Run the server.*
>
> Download any plugins you want and put them in the "plugins" folder.
>
> In the server properties file, set the IP to 127.0.0.1
>
> Start Minecraft and go to Multiplayer.
>
> Type "localhost" as the server IP.
>
> Enjoy! You'll experience NO lag, and other players cannot join your server. It is the same as playing Singleplayer, except you can have all the plugins you want!

*More information on that subject can be found [here](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Setting_up_a_server).

Good luck!

-HewwwoCraziness